# std::unique with predicate comparing std::string not removing duplicate

Tags: c++, c++11, predicate, stdvector, duplicates

Unless I am missing something or missunderstand the mechanism (very likely) Shouldn't the "1" duplicate not exist in this vector ?

```
chunks.erase( std::unique ( chunks.begin(), chunks.end(), 
                           []( std::string &s1, std::string &s2 ){ 
                              return ( s1.compare(s2) == 0 ? true : false );}), 
                           chunks.end() );
```

Before Executing the above:

```
1       l:1
1+      l:2
1+1     l:3
1+1=    l:4
+       l:1
+1      l:2
+1=     l:3
1       l:1
1=      l:2
=       l:1
```

After executing the above code:

```
1       l:1
1+      l:2
1+1     l:3
1+1=    l:4
+       l:1
+1      l:2
+1=     l:3
1       l:1
1=      l:2
=       l:1
```

I have tried without a predicate (assuming std::strings that are identical would be removed). For some reason the "ones" are identified as identical? I  have looked at their length (assuming a whitespace was stuck as a prefix or postfix) but they have the same length.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You really shouldn't need to use this predicate as it is used by default. Can you please add more code as what are the exact strings and how you print the output?

Comment: Minor nitpick regarding `return ( s1.compare(s2) == 0 ? true : false );` : this is redundant, just use `return ( s1.compare(s2) == 0)`;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are (probably) misunderstanding something.

`std::unique` only removes contiguous duplicates, so if you wish to remove all duplicates a precondition to applying `std::unique` is to sort your range using the same predicate.

Answer (score 5):

`std::unique` assumes that non-unique elements are adjacent, as they would be if (for one example) `chunks` were sorted.  This allows `std::unique` to have O(n) complexity.

If you want to maintain a specific order in your `vector` and remove duplicates, that's a problem with O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity.  You can use the logic provided here to do that.

```
// Create a new vector without the duplicates
std::vector<string> unique_chunks;
for (std::vector<string>::iterator x = chunks.begin(); x != chunks.end();) {
  if ( unique_chunks.find(*x) != unique_chunks.end() ) {
    unique_chunks.push_back( *x );
  }
}

// Make chunks hold this new vector (allowing the old vector to be destroyed)
std::swap( chunks, unique_chunks );
```

And no, you didn't need that predicate.

Comment: It could be done O(n log n) too, if I understand correct(sort + unique + sort)

Comment: @RiaD: Unless your two sorts have different ordering criteria, (sort + unique + sort) is exactly equivalent to (sort + unique).

Comment: @RiaD Perhaps?  It would be more like (sort + unique + **un**-sort) though.  I can't think of a good un-sort approach though.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, surely they are different

Comment: @RiaD: What's different?  The ordering criteria?  Then what is the ordering criteria for the second sort?

Comment: @Drew, ok, I'll post it as another solution

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in other answer, `unique` deletes contiguous blocks of duplicate, if you need remove duplicates and preserve order of rest elements(order of first occurrence, here) in `O(N log N)` time you may do the following:

```
template<typename T>
bool bySecond(const pair<T, int>& a, const pair<T, int>& b) {
    return a.second < b.second;
}

template<typename T>
bool firstEqual(const pair<T, int>& a, const pair<T, int>& b) {
    return a.first == b.first;
}

template<typename it>
it yourUnique(it begin, it end){
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<it>::value_type value_t;
    vector<pair<value_t, int>> v;
    for(it c = begin; c != end; ++c){
        v.push_back(make_pair(*c, v.size())); // second is start index;
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // sort by value then by index
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end(), firstEqual<value_t>), v.end());
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), bySecond<value_t>); // restore order.
    it c = begin;

    for(const auto& x: v){
       *(c++) = x.first;
    }
    return it;
}
```

Possibility to have own predicate isn't implemented. It's possible but one disadvantage is that you will have to provide `less-than` function, not `equality` one, that's maybe impossible in some cases.

Comment: +1 Okay, clever.  But you need a predicate for `unique` which ignores `second`.  Otherwise, it won't remove anything, because every pair is unique by its `second` value.

Comment: Nice.  It's verbose, but for big vectors you win the big O test.  *Edit: I said "clever", but when multiple devs use that word, it starts to get a certain smell* :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley,  sure. I'll add it now

Answer (score 1):

The `std::unique` algorithm assumes that the input range is in order and removes duplicates by comparing two consecutive values. To be able to use the algorithm you will need to sort the input first.