# remove duplicates in array using method

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove duplicate numbers from an array using a method but, unfortunately I can not solve it. This what I have done so far:

```
//method code
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] input){
    int []r=new int[input.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
            if ((input[i]==input[j]) && (i != j)) {
                return r;
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) and the `contains` method.

Comment: do you know how to add elements to an array?

Comment: Do you want to create your own method to remove duplicates? Otherwise as MichaelIT said you can use set, where set dont allow duplicate items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Remove Duplicates from an Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056729/java-remove-duplicates-from-an-array) among numerous others

Comment: no, actually ineed to solve it without 'set'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from integer array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912004/remove-duplicates-from-integer-array)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is add all elements in a Set.

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] input){
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        set.add(input[i]);
    }
    //by adding all elements in the Set, the duplicates where removed.
    int[] array = new int[set.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer num : set) {
        array[i++] = num;           
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: This will change the order of elements, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: thanks @nakosspy but i need to solve it without **set** what other way

Comment: Is it a school assignment?

Comment: @Thilo I think that there's a mistake there. Instead of if(isExists(result, i)) it must be if(!isExists(result, i)). Can you edit it?

Comment: @nakosspy: Looks like it. Also, the result array should probably be shortened. It's not my answer, so I don't want to just edit it. And it would be better for B'Tasneem to figure out the solution by himself. You should put a comment there.

Comment: OK, I agree, B'Tasneem has enough info to figure it out himself.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way:

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] input){
    boolean[] duplicate = new boolean[input.length];
    int dups = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(duplicate[i])
            continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            if ((input[i]==input[j])) {
                duplicate[j] = true; // j is duplicate
                ++dups;
            }
        }
    }
    int[] r = new int[input.length] - dups;
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i)
        r[index++] = input[i];
    return r;
}
```

It can also be done in `O(n log n)`. [C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413943/stdunique-with-predicate-comparing-stdstring-not-removing-duplicate/15414984#15414984)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates in your collection, well you shouldn't be using an Array in the first place. Use a set instead and you will never duplicates to remove in the first place.

If you only "sometimes" want no duplicates, well you better explain your situation further.

Comment: "If you don't want duplicates in your collection, well you shouldn't be using an Array in the first place". That is like saying "if you need command line arguments to be integers, you should not use `main(String[] argv)`". There are such things as *input data*, and it does not always come in the form most convenient to the program.

Comment: true, there is sometimes input data in a format you cannot constrain. But these situations are rarer than your think, and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Same goes for output constraints.